# Lightning - 'delete' button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button

I am trying to create a 'delete' custom button for Lightning, in similarity to the one existing in the Classic details view? :

[image]

I was referred to the following Lightning Data Service (beta) article: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_delete_record.htm

I used the article to create the component, but after adding the custom action to my Case layout, the following error populates: 
"This entity is not currently supported by force:recordData."

Further reading about this error, concludes the Case object is not yet supported for 'force:recordData'.

Is there any other alternative to create a simple 'deleted' button for Cases?

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Data Service supports the entities mentioned in the link below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm

So Case object is not supported yet.